# MongoDB Performing MapReduce getting NaN values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv, mapreduce, nan

Given a data set for stocks, my task is to generate the average performance of that certain stock per month given a year's worth of data. (the key is the month)

For some unknown there are certain months that return NaN value in its performance average.

I import my dataset to mongodb from this file linked below: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ltsj7C_DRLYXltQnBLTTk2Mk0/view?usp=sharing

after importing, I run my mapreduce algorithm and check the results using 
db.BR.report.find()

Here's my code for the mapreduce:

```
// mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 -d contempoFinal -c BR --type csv --file /Users/eddrichjanzzenang/Desktop/BR.csv --headerline


var map = function(){

    var date = this.Date.substring(5,7);
    var p = ((this.Close - this.Open)/ this.Close) * 100;


    emit({date: date}, {p:p})

}



var reduce = function(key, values){

    var total = 0; 

    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        total += values[i].p;
    }


    if(values.length != 0){
        total = total/values.length;
    }

    return {ave:total}

    // return {values:values}

}


db.runCommand({
    mapReduce: "BR",
    map: map,
    reduce: reduce,
    out: "BR.reports"
})


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------This is the cause of the error ---------------------------------------
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// return {values:values} instead of return {ave:total} in the reduce function

//run the ff command: db.BR.reports.find().pretty()

// As you can see, another values array has been added inside the original values array.


//  "_id" : {
//  "date" : "08"
// },
// "value" : {
//  "values" : [
//      {
//          "values" : [
//              {
//                  "p" : -2.078157439320257
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : -0.5431533054662951
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : 0.9795132377415724
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : -3.9067422810333916
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : 0.1845049200491997
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : 7.313954241902089
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : -1.964815364505311
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : -1.973890069845128
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : -1.3640210674629443
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : -0.3878227361674579
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : -0.25217148366968656
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : 1.1589458521552969
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : 2.3657055385471732
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : 0.5798810913377168
//              },
//              {
//                  "p" : -1.9705884532497502
//              }
//          ]
//      },
//      {
//          "p" : 0.7537092460991003
//      },
//      {
//          "p" : 0.40904829064892917
//      },
//      {
//          "p" : -0.18791946308724908
//      },
//      {
//          "p" : -2.4136067584642555
//      },
//      {
//          "p" : 1.373917062874929
//      },
//      {
//          "p" : 0.05451349290034214
//      }
//  ]
// }
```

Is there any solution for this you may recommend? I would very grateful to any input regarding this. Thank you very much!

Comment: after some fiddling, I have found the cause of the NaN by instead returning the values array in the reduce function: return {values:values} by running db.BR.reports.find().pretty() I found that in the record month:08, another values array is inserted in the original values array. Instead of performing arithmetic on a number it performs it in the extra values array producing NaN value